# Является ли корректным употребление таких форм причастий?

Tags: причастия

Произносящийся тост. Тост, который себя произносит, так?   Или все же произносимый тост?

Пишущаяся книга. Книга, которая пишет себя. Какая тут логика?

Соответственно, почему тут ошибка?

> Конкурс, проводящийся организаторами, очень понравился участникам.

Ведь получается, что конкурс проводится организаторами (страдательный залог).

Comment: Ну мало логики, не тот суффикс. Хотя бывает пишущаяся буква - букву которую нужно писать определенным образам. Но на счёт тоста - не верно, и насчет конкурса тоже. Ся - это возвратный залог, а ный, мый, тый - страдательный.

Comment: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/brokgauz_efron/97616/Страдательный https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/brokgauz_efron/23324/Возвратный - возвратный может совпадать со страдательным, но страдательный не всегда возвратный.

Comment: То есть у действительного причастия с "ся" не может быть деятеля в творительном падеже?

Comment: Ну а как быть с буквой: пишущаяся буква - буква, которая пишется. Он ж не сама себя пишет

Comment: Предметы и объекты не субъектны, а -ся - это возвратный суффикс сокращение от "себя". У предметов нет себя. Убиться - убить себя, добиться - достать своими усилиями... Может быть ся и у причастий - добивающийся, но когда речь идет о том, кто может быть субъектом, о человеке, может о животном и тп. Буква имеет идею, то есть это чья-то реализованная идея в определенной символике, замысел некий, поэтому буква может быть пишущаяся определенным образом. Насчёт тоста сложнее, но наверное можно извернуться...

Comment: То есть конкурс проводящийся в соответствии с регламентом проведения... Какая-то бюрократическая чепуха. Ну и как бы абсолютно безличное, как только появляются руководители или еще кто, конкурс сразу становится проводимым кем-то, в соответствии с чем-то.

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Конкурс все равно кто-то проводит, а букву кто-то пишет, у нас же не "самопишущаяся" буква.

Comment: Это какая-то хрень из переводов инглиша: "Тренинг корпоративный – обучающий групповой семинар, проводящийся коучем по заказу руководителя фирмы/предприятия и тому подобного." Картаслов. Дело в том, что на западе воспринимают не человека, а статус. Коуч - это статус. Вот руководители фирмы заказали проведение семинара в соответствии с регламентом, где человек проводит его в статусе коуча. То есть он уже не совсем человек- субъект, а человек функция - коуч. Поэтому тут как бы коуч подчинён организационным моментам конкурса...

Comment: Но по-русски это криво звучит всё-таки, потому что у нас нет статусов отдельно от личности человека, что ли.

Comment: https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/проводящийся - примеры как видно после 2010 года, то есть это какое-то новое явление, неологизмы... Возможно, различие возвратного и страдательного залога есть в русском, но нет в каком-нить инглише...

Comment: Хотите разобраться [изучите это](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) там не много, но много проясняется Ну и надо понимать, что в грамматике часто нет абсолютных ответов

Answer (score 0):

**Логика в языке** всегда есть.

Иногда существуют **две формы** с одним значением (но **частотность** их употребления разная!), а некоторые формы вообще **не образуются.** Существование форм можно проверить по Зализняку.

**Пример 1**

Тост, который произносится, — **произносимый** тост.

Тост, который произносят, — произносящийся  тост.

**Пример 2**

Книга, которая пишется, — нет формы с суффиксом ЕМ.

Книга, которую пишут,  — пишущаяся книга (форма практически не используется).

**Пример 3**

Конкурс, который проводится, — **проводимый** конкурс.

Конкурс, который проводят, — проводящийся конкурс.

Comment: Вопрос все же в другом. Почему "произносящийся" тост, если его произносят. Действительное причастие показывает, что действие производит сам предмет. В этом примере не так. ТО же самое с конкурсом и книгой. Совершает действие не сам предмет, а кто-то сторонний.

Comment: Несущийся поезд - поезд несется, качающееся дерево - дерево качается. Тут  же не так. И вы не ответили на вопрос, правильны ли данные формы.

Comment: Я вам рассказала в общем случае, почему существуют две формы страдательного залога с одинаковым значением,  а также  всё это относительно двух примеров. Этого достаточно. По этому образцу вы самостоятельно можете решить остальные задачи.

Comment: Я не о том, что существует две формы. А об употреблении форм. Я предполагаю, что употребление таких форм действительных причастий при существовании страдательных - ошибка.

Comment: Слова "произносящийся" я вообще в словаре не нашла.

Comment: Причастие - это форма глагола,  а в словарях даются прилагательные. И вот формы на -МЫЙ  обычно считаются прилагательными, а причастиями бывают при особых условиях.

Comment: Слово "произносящий" в этом же словаре есть.

Comment: И это может быть. Вот у Зализняка я видела: строимый и строящийся, в теории обе формы возможны.  Частотность разная.

Comment: Я не против того, что образовать такие формы можно. Они вполне могут быть и словарными, дело в другом: когда они употребляются, если основная функция действительного причастия  - показать, что действие совершает предмет.

Comment: Это же страдательный залог (частица СЯ).  Но форма на МЫЙ удобнее, поэтому используется.  А форма на СЯ не запрещена, но не востребована.  А значение у них одинаковое.

Comment: Этот пример с конкурсом из задания ЕГЭ, там сказано, что возможен только вариант со страдательными причастием.

Comment: Я читала одну статью, в которой говорилось о том. что действительное причастие в страдательном залоге можно использовать вместо страдательного только в том случае, если форма страдательного не существует или мало употребляется. Но формы в этих примерах такими вряд ли можно назвать.

Comment: Имеются в виду формы страдательных причастий, а не действительных.

Comment: Как это вряд ли? Я и без статьи по одной грамматике их так назвала. Просто посмотрела возможные ограничения для разных форм причастий.

Comment: Если скажут так: "Роман, пишущийся писателем", то ошибки не будет, поскольку форму причастия страдательного нет, но в наших примерах все формы страдательных причастий есть.

Comment: То есть вы скажете, что пример с конкурсом верен?

Comment: Я не могу вам сказать больше, чем я уже сказала по заданному вопросу. Зачем повторяться.